# Android show marker onClick button

Tags: android, parsing, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I want to plot all the coordinates of latitude and longitude values I get. Check the first and last of the plot and change with different icons. Add Poly lines on each mark plot and buttons on popup that can hide/dismiss.

The problem I am having now is that whenever I remove the for-loop outside the button I am having a null pointer error.

```
      @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map1);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        new GetVehicleValue().execute();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contact_us, container, false);
Button b = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button3);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        });

        if(vehicleHolder.size() != 0) {
        for(int i =0; i < vehicleHolder.size(); i++) {
            createMarker(i,vehicleHolder.get(i).getLatitude(),vehicleHolder.get(i).getLongitude(),vehicleHolder.get(i).getVehicle());
        }
    }

        return v;
    }

    public void createMarker(int index, String latitude, String longitude, String vehicle) {
        // Adding the taped point to the ArrayList
        BitmapDescriptor image = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.bus);
        Double lat = Double.parseDouble(latitude);
        Double Longitude = Double.parseDouble(longitude);
        float color = 0;

        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(lat, Longitude))
                .anchor(0.5f, 0.5f)
                .title("title")
                .snippet("snippet"  )
                .icon(image));


    }

    class GetVehicleValue extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONArray jr = new JSONArray(jsonStr);

                    vehicleHolder = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonStr.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jb = (JSONObject) jr.getJSONObject(i);
                        plate_num = jb.getString("plate_num");
                        gps_num = jb.getString("gps_num");
                        location = jb.getString("location");
                        date = jb.getString("date");
                        time = jb.getString("time");
                        lat = jb.getString("lat");
                        lng = jb.getString("lng");
                        engine = jb.getString("engine");
                        remarks = jb.getString("remarks");

                        vehicleHolder.add(new VehicleHolder(lat, lng));

                    }

                } catch (final JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Log.d("JSON:", "is null");
            }

            return null;
        }
```

Comment: Never silently swallow Exceptions `catch (final JSONException e) {

                }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your location model class:

```
public class LocationHolder {

    private String longitude,latitude,location,direction;

    public LocationHolder(String longitude, String latitude, String location, String direction) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.location = location;
        this.direction = direction;
    }

    public String getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(String longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public String getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(String latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public String getDirection() {
        return direction;
    }

    public void setDirection(String direction) {
        this.direction = direction;
    }
}
```

Parsing :

```
public static ArrayList<LocationHolder>list_location=new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);
    String account = c.getString("account");
    String trxdate = c.getString("trxdate");
    String trxtime = c.getString("trxtime");
    String longitude = c.getString("long");
    String latitude = c.getString("lat");
    String location = c.getString("location");
    String direction = c.getString("direction");
    String compass = c.getString("compass");
    String id = c.getString("id");
    String remarks = c.getString("remarks");
    String status = c.getString("status");
    String kmrun = c.getString("kmrun");
    String speed = c.getString("speed");
    String totalkm = c.getString("totalkm");
    String engine = c.getString("engine");
    String plateno = c.getString("plateno");    

    list_location.add(new LocationHolder(longitude,latitude,location,direction,))
}
```

button click

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        for(int i=0;i<list_location.length();i++)
        {
            createMarker(list_location.get(i).getLatitude(),list_location.get(i).getLongitude(),list_location.get(i).getLocation());
        }
});
```

createMarker Function:

```
private void createMarker(String latitude, String longitude,String snippet) {

    BitmapDescriptor icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.map_pin);
    Double lat = Double.parseDouble(latitude);
    Double Longitude = Double.parseDouble(longitude);

    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(lat, Longitude))
            .anchor(0.5f, 0.5f)
            .title(title)
            .snippet(snippet)
            .icon(icon));

    googleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new MarkerInfoWindowAdapter());

    googleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {

            for (int i = 0; i < locationList.size(); i++) {
                  Log.d("TAG","getLatitude:"+list_location.get(i).getLatitude()+" getLongitude:"+list_location.get(i).getLongitude());
                if (marker.getSnippet().equals(list_location.get(i).getLocation())) {
                  Log.d("TAG","Selected Marker");
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

MarkerInfoWindowAdapter:Add your custom window info UI

```
  public class MarkerInfoWindowAdapter implements GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter {

    public MarkerInfoWindowAdapter() {
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(final Marker marker) {
       View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_mapview, null);

        TextView markerLabel = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
        markerLabel.setText(marker.getTitle());

        return v;
    }
}
```

MyFragment

```
GoogleMap googleMap;

class MyFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        googleMap = map;
        setUpMap();
    }

    /*set up map*/
    private void setUpMap() {
        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        googleMap.setTrafficEnabled(true);
        googleMap.setIndoorEnabled(true);
        googleMap.setBuildingsEnabled(true);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(new LatLng(0.0, 0.0)).zoom(15).build();
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

        //set marker here
    }
}
```

Try this to store list into array list,

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.+'
}
```

Set the values

```
    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("AppPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor PrefsEditor = preferences.edit();


Gson gson = new Gson();

String jsonText = gson.toJson(list_location );
prefsEditor.putString("key", jsonText);
prefsEditor.commit();
```

Retrieve the values

```
List<LocationHolder> addArray  = new ArrayList<>();
Gson gson = new Gson();
String jsonText = Prefs.getString("key", null);
String[] text = gson.fromJson(jsonText, String[].class);

addArray = Arrays.asList(text);
addArray = new ArrayList(addArray);
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for that great answer. My question now is how can I use list_location.length() that was on for loop of btn that is on the ui thread? There's an error `cannot resolve method 'length()'`

Comment: @JaysonJohn use list_location.size() .please check updated code

Comment: Hi, user2025187. That resolved my question. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, user2025187, can you change the icon of the beginning and end arrow and put description??

Comment: @JaysonJohn which icon?

Comment: Hi, user2025187. What I mean is Different detail description on each marker like custom popupwindow with description that can't be close with button

Comment: Hi, user2025187. I want to popup all this values 
account, trxdate , trxtime , longitude, latitude ,location ,direction , compass etc. on textview here `TextView markerLabel = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
        markerLabel.setText(marker.getTitle());` Also, is it necessary to create this new class MarkerInfoWindowAdapter??


`String account = c.getString("account");`
    `String trxdate = c.getString("trxdate");`
    `String trxtime = c.getString("trxtime");`
    `String longitude = c.getString("long");`
    `String latitude = c.getString("lat");`

    `etc.`

Comment: In same class u create MarkerInfoWindowAdapter class.Create UI for custom popup or you can concatenate all required data into string and set to   single textview 'markerLabel'

Comment: Hi, user2025187. I am having error cannot resolve method 'getLayoutInflater()'

Comment: use getActivity(). getLayoutInflater()

Comment: Hi, user2025187. I created a new class named it MarkerInfoWindowAdapter . However I am getting error cannot resolve method either by getLayoutInflater() or getActivity() .getLayoutInflater()

Comment: Do not create new class.Create class inside MapFragment  after createMarker function.And you creating inside Fragment so you need getActivity() .getLayoutInflater()

Comment: Hi user2025187, using markerLabel.setText(marker.getTitle()); how may I display different coordinates per latitude?

Comment: pass location name to create Marker function and set location name as title

Comment: Hi, user2025187. How may I add polyline on this code??

Pls. check updated code above. Thanks!

Comment: check http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/drawing-polyline-and-markers-along-the-tapped-positions-in-google-map-android-api-v2-using-arraylist/

Comment: implements your  fragment using OnMapReadyCallback and in onMapReady setup your map and then set marker.Check updated code

Comment: hi user2025187, is there a way for me to get the value of ArrayList<LocationHolder>list_location on another class without having a null pointer?

Comment: @JaysonJohn Check updated code.Make list_location  static and access using classname.list_location

Comment: hi user2025187, I am having public and static is not allowed here.

Comment: declare as global variable

Comment: Hi user2025187, will there be any other way aside from declaring it as global variable? like getter and Setter?.

Comment: Save your array list into  Shared Preferences and fetch in another class.check updated code

Comment: Hi user2025187, cannot find symbol Prefs and incompatible LocationHolder, found String. Also, with that code how will I get like `for(int i =0, i<list_location.size(); i++) {
list_location.get(i).getLatitude();}`

Comment: Hi user2025187, what is `com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 3`

Answer (score 0):

Make `location` and `direction` to be fields

```
String lattitude;
String longitude;
```

then in `doInBackground` change the code to be

```
lattitude = c.getString("lattitude");
longitude= c.getString("longitude");
```

then they may be used in `onClick`